# iphone memory allocation problem

Tags: iphone, memory-management

hay all..
i hope every thing is good
im a new iphone developer and i did an application and when i finished i test it through allocation test in instrument and shocked from the results..it stole
very very big memory and i don't know what i must do..in the same time i release every variable i was used BUT the real problem was that the application load man images and contains custom cells and custom tables with custom navigation
please help me

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not releasing your objects after you're finished with them, or you're loading an unrealistic amount of images / data into a handheld device. It's pretty hard to help in this instance if we can't see your code.

I found the [Stanford iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225) course really helpful, and they go through the logistics of memory management really well. It's something you really need a good understanding of before/as your write your apps.